# On scroll event not firing

Tags: jquery, scroll, zurb-foundation

I have the following at: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/aldemair-productions/project.html

```
$('.main-wrapper').on('scroll', function(){
    console.log('ffsdfsd');
});
```

but it's not firing, I need to know as soon as main-wrapper hits the header so that I can make "secondary-nav" fixed as well.

This almost worked:

```
// $('.off-canvas-wrapper').on('scroll', function(){
//  console.log($('.off-canvas-wrapper').scrollTop());
//  if($('.off-canvas-wrapper').scrollTop() == 418 || $('.off-canvas-wrapper').scrollTop() > 417) {
//      $('.secondary-nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
//  }
//  else {
//      $('.secondary-nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
//  }
// });
```

but unfortunately "$('.off-canvas-wrapper').scrollTop()" changes based on when the window is resized.

Comment: Have u tried this $('body').on('scroll', '.main-wrapper', function(){     console.log('ffsdfsd'); });

Comment: there is no need to delegate..

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're attaching the scroll event to your `.main-content` element.

According to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) the scroll event only works on the window objects, scrollable frames/elements.

> The scroll event is sent to an element when the user scrolls to a
>   different place in the element. It applies to window objects, but also
>   to scrollable frames and elements with the overflow CSS property set
>   to scroll

Try attaching the scroll event to the window object and checking the `scrollTop` vs the `.main-content` top.

```js
$(function() {

  var $main = $(".main-wrapper"),
    top = $main.offset().top;

  function affix() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (top < scrollTop) {
      // apply css to fix navigation
      alert('affix navigation');
      $('.secondary-nav').addClass('fixed-nav');
    } else {
      $('.secondary-nav').removeClass('fixed-nav');
    }
  }

  $(window).scroll(affix);

});
```

```css
.top-content {
  height: 500px;
}
.main-wrapper{
  height: 800px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="top-content">
  <p>scroll down</p>
</div>
<div class="main-wrapper">
  <p>content here</p>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that this doesn't get called at all: $(window).scroll(affix);

Comment: Are you sure the document is ready?  https://jsfiddle.net/enkicode/tk661c8t/ works for me.

Comment: I am getting the following: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined. It is inside document ready

Comment: @Alex  My fault... My element is called `main-content` and yours is `main-wrapper`, try changing it and see if it works.

Comment: updated but still nothing: http://www.alessandrosantese.com/aldemair-productions/project.html

Comment: It's not the script, it's your css and site layout. Open up the dev console and highlight main-wrapper, it's content extends to the top of the screen which is why nothing is happening. Fixing that would be another question.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might by the wrong element you're applying the event to. Try this:

```
$(window).on('scroll', function(){
     console.log('ffsdfsd');
});
```